# How to cause manually ActiveRecord RecordInvalid in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Entry:** I have attribute class that derive from one of the `ActiveRecord` types and implement method cast(value) which transforms provided value to derived Active Record type. In our case we perform transformation only when the provided value is a String otherwise the default integer casting is performed. Private method `to_minutes` converts formatted time to an integer representing spent minutes. I assumed that `1d = 8h = 480m`. E.g. result of `to_minutes`('1d 1h 1m') = 541. (I used this resource [Custom Attributes in Ruby on Rails 5 ActiveRecord](https://www.ideamotive.co/blog/custom-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails-5-activerecord)

If the `string` that came has no numbers, I need to return a validation error, and set this error to the `@card.errors`. How should I do it? I try:

```
if time.scan(/\d/).empty?
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(InvalidRecord.new)
end
```

But it does not work, I get an error

```sh
NameError in CardsController#update
uninitialized constant CardDuration::Type::InvalidRecord
Extracted source (around line #15):
```

I create my own attribute for integer type:

```rb
class CardDuration
  class Type < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
    def cast(value)
      if value.is_a?(String)
        to_seconds(value)
      else
        super
      end
    end

    private

    def to_seconds(time)
      if time.scan(/\d/).empty?
           return raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new, { errors: {message: 'Duration is too short (minimum is 1 number)'} }
      end
      time_sum = 0
      time.split(' ').each do |time_part|
        value = time_part.to_i
        type = time_part[-1,1]
        case type
        when 'm'
          value
        when 'h'
          value *= 60
        when 'd'
          value *= 8*60
        else
          value
        end
        time_sum += value
      end
      time_sum
    end
  end
end
```

and inside model:

```rb
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  validates :duration,  length: { within: 0..14880 }
  attribute :duration, CardDuration::Type.new
end
```

Also validation doesn't work, and I do not understand why.
Thanks)
Inside controller this field can only be updated, so I need set the error to the @card.errors:

```rb
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @card.update(card_params)
      flash[:success] = "Card was successfully updated."
    else
      flash[:error] = @card.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
      render status: 422
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      return e.record
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest separating of typecasting and validation to prevent getting an error during an assignment because it broke the usual flow when you get validation errors after calling `valid?` or `save`. If `time` doesn't have any numbers in it return `nil`. `validates :duration, length: { within: 0..14880 }, presence: true` will do the rest of the job.

Comment: Thank-you @Yakov - in my case your option worked. Just return nil and it return validation error.

Answer (score 2):

in  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(...) you need to pass structure, which have method 'errors' [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid/new/class).
try to `raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self.new)`
or write or own class, with method `errors`, which will be handle your exeptions

Comment: Something like thisI try but get an error, NoMethodError (super: no superclass method `to_seconds'. I think I need to use super to get all Card method and rise correct error, but I don't how.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see in your code is the way you're raising the invalid record error.

The correct way to do that would be-

`raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`